# How can I define the query behind the people webpart on SharePoint Online Classic?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I want to re-define the query behind the people webpart on SharePoint Online Classic to show all people rather than having to search for a user. But it seems you can only change the type of card from compact to descriptive. Any idea how to add query text to my query.

Answer (score 0):

Update the search result webpart query as *.

Sample demo.

[image]

Comment: That's a different version of SharePoint so the tabs at the top are not available on SharePoint Classic Online.